# Executing child before parent in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    int pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot create a child process");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {

        printf("I am the child process. %d \n", getpid());
        printf("The child process is done. \n");
        fflush(stdout); // it does not write immediately to a disk.
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {

        printf("I am the parent process.%d \n", getpid());
        sleep(5); // sleep does not works
        pid = wait(&status); // want to wait until the child is complited
        printf("The parent process is done. \n");
        fflush(stdout); // it does not write immediately to a disk.
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Hi guys, I am currently trying to create a child process. So far so good, however, what I am trying now is to execute the child first and print out and always print out the message "The parent process is done" last.

```
I am the parent process.28847  
I am the child process. 28848 
The child process is done.
The parent process is done.
```

Currently is printing this:

```
I am the parent process.28847 
The parent process is done.
I am the child process. 28848 
The child process is done.
```

It is my first time using forking so I am not really confident in what I am doing, I've tried sleep and wait(&status) to try wait until the child process is finished and then execute the parent but something is not working.

P.S. sorry for the bad layout, fist time using stackoverflow.

Comment: You should probably use [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) or 
[`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html).

Comment: In your code, "The parent process is done" will be printed as last everytime (since you are using `wait()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have managed to fix it. I am going to check mutex and semaphores and how can I improve it.

Comment: What makes you think that getting a mutex or a semaphore involved would be an improvement?  Getting rid of the `sleep()` call would be an improvement.  Having the parent call `wait()` or `waitpid()` at the appropriate point relative to its other work would be an improvement.  Given that that can *solve* the problem as it was presented, and that you do want to call `wait()` regardless, why would it be better to introduce needless extra complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waitpid(-1, NULL, 0); or wait(NULL); This will block parent until all child processes have finished.
If it works then you do not need to use sleep.

Slight modification to your code:

```
else
{
    int status =0;
    printf("I am the parent process.%d \n", getpid());
    status= waitpid(-1, NULL, 0); // want to wait until the child is complete
    //Also check if child process terminated properly
    if(status==0)
    {
        printf("Child process terminated properly");
    }   
    else
    {
       printf("Child process terminated with error");
    }

    printf("The parent process is done. \n");

    fflush(stdout); // it does not write immediately to a disk.

    exit(1);
}
```